# ASP.NET C# error: Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle10g

Forgive me, I'm a beginner, but I'm making a basic "convert Fahrenheit to Celsius" program, and I can't figure out the above error. My code right now, looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     double fahrenheit = double.Parse(farTemp.Text);
     lblCelsius.Text = (5 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32).ToString();


 } 
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Convert Temperature</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Please enter the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox
     Width="75"
    id="farTemp"
    Runat="server" /> 
    <br />
    <br /> 

    <asp:Button
    id="Button1"
    Text="Convert to Celsius"
    OnClick="Button1_Click" 
    Runat="server" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
    Degrees in Celsius:
    <asp:Label
    id="lblCelsius"
    Runat="server" />
    <br />


    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The error appears in line 7. The strange thing is, when I change the '*' symbol to a '+' symbol, the program works (except for the fact that it does the wrong math). Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bracket is in the wrong place. You are doing fahrenheit - 32, converting that to a string, then trying to multiply it. Try this:

```
lblCelsius.Text = ((5 / 9) * fahrenheit - 32).ToString();
```